# Animate HTML5 Progress value using purely CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, progress-bar, css-animations

[My progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxPL.png):

[image]

Is it possible to animate an HTML5 progress value with CSS only?

I can style the progress element's background and progress colours, but can I apply an animation, such as a shimmer effect, to the progress value?

```
/* Reset default */
.wcl-progress-meter progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
   appearance: none !important;
}


/* Progress bar background */
.wcl-progress-meter  progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: #8499E0 !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px #0a369d;
}


/* Progress bar value */
.wcl-progress-meter  progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: #0a369d !important;
}
```

The website is a WordPress website with plugins; I've snooped into some of the plugin files and some PHP/HTML5 I believe creates the progress meter is here:

```
                <div class="wcl-progress-meter <?php if ($product->is_max_tickets_met()) {
                echo 'full';
            } ?>">

                <?php if (!get_field('hide_ticket_minmax')): ?>
                    <span class="current"><strong><?php echo $lottery_participants_count ?>/<?php echo $max_tickets ?> <?php _e('', 'diyraffle'); ?></strong></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <progress max="<?php echo $max_tickets ?>" value="<?php echo $lottery_participants_count ?>" low="<?php echo $min_tickets ?>"></progress>
            </div>
```

I looked at some tutorials online but they didn't animate using the progress element they used divs!

Comment: Do you want to apply the shimmer effect to the progress element itself or to the elements that are loading?

Comment: I want to add the shimmer effect to the progress element itself; the darker blue portion of the image I attached in the OP!

Comment: This may sound ridiculous, but what's the relevant HTML (and JavaScript, if any is being used)? This is a prompt to add that to your question, in order that it's easy for us to reproduce your problem and offer practicable suggestions/answers based on your current use-case.

Comment: I've edited the OP with the code I believe creates the progress bar!

Comment: It seems this is not possible, can you use JavaScript or custom HTML elements?

Comment: Why is it not possible? I can try to edit this plugin file!